# awk one liner: replace xml tags

Tags: xml, replace, awk

I have got an xml file containing some attributes like

```
<string name="my/ attribute" optional="true">
  <description>some text</description>
  <value>some text again</value>
</string>
```

I would like to change the value (which does not necessarily have to be "some text again") by the string "none". I tried the following on the command line:

```
 awk '/<string name="my\/ attribute" optional="true">/,/<\/string>/ {sub(/<value>(.*)<\/value>/,"<value>none</value>")}1' my.xml > my_new.xml
```

This somehow works ok, but the result is as follows:

```
<string name="my/ attribute" optional="true">
  <description>some text</description>
  <value>some text again<\/value>
</string>
```

Why is the / (slash) in the  tag escaped?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Daniela.

Comment: Awk is not an XML parser.  While you may be able to get a solution that works to some extent, it *will* have limitations, won't work in every case, etc.  I suggest you look at using a real XML parser to do this.  Perl, PHP, etc may all be options.

Comment: The output you provide looks to be the same as the input except for the escaped slash in the closing value tag.  Not sure why you say this works ok when the some text again has not been changed to none.  Not sure what the trailing 1 after the function body enclosing the sub() is for.  Also I would think you need to escape the literal double quotes.

Comment: oops. copy&paste error: the output should be <value>none<\/value>

Comment: @Daniela - you should [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12316757/edit) with the fix, rather than relying on comments for such clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the inconsistencies in your question that Richard pointed out are accidental:

```
$ cat input.xml
<string name="my/ attribute" optional="true">
  <description>some text</description>
  <value>some text again</value>
</string>

$ awk '/<string/{doit=1} doit{sub(/<value>[^<]+<\/value>/, "<value>none</value>"); print} /<\/string>/{doit=0}' input.xml 
<string name="my/ attribute" optional="true">
  <description>some text</description>
  <value>none</value>
</string>

$
```

This is WEE bit safer than your script, in that it will handle minified XML (i.e. whitespace removed, all on e line), but it won't handle `<value>` that is split over multiple lines.

I do recommend looking in to [Perl's XML::Simple](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/parsing-xml-documents-with-perls-xmlsimple/5363190) or [PHP's SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).  It won't be a one-liner, but it will work MUCH more reliably.

Comment: This only replaces the text inside the tag, it doesn't add the backslash to the close tag, as the OP specified.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use standard text tools to process XML - always use XML tools. Otherwise you (or your customers) will end up among the hundreds of people who post questions on this list asking what to do about the fact that they have ill-formed XML to process. It's simply too hard to get it right by hand, catering for all the edge cases that can arise. For example, do you know the rules for where whitespace is allowed within start and end tags? Judging from your sample code, you don't appear to.